# It's the time to do

Tags: definite-article

Many people say 'It's **the** time to *do*' is unidiomatic. They say it's always 'It's time to *do*.'

It's time to go home.
It's time to start the work.
It's time to go.

Even in a situation where 'going' has been evoked, and the action is awaited and focused on, you would not put 'the' before 'time':

> A troop of soldiers have discussed when to attack their enemy. A man
>   suggested that they start fighting when they see the enemy's tanks
>   turn to the west because the sides are their most vulnerable. The
>   vehicles do so indeed when the troop catch the enemy's radio signaling
>   ZZZXXX. They agreed on the timing.
>
> At 3:00 am, yes, they hear it.
>
> The captain says '**It's [the] time to go!**' [XXX] to mean the wrong usage.
>
> (My rendition)

Then, how would you justify the use of 'the' in the following sentences? Do they stand without 'the'?

> (1) Stir that Manhattan. Shake that sidecar. With the holiday season in
>   gear, **it's the time to press the cocktail bar into service**.
>
> Thanks to the renaissance of craft cocktails in restaurants and
>   gastropubs, the bar cart and built-in wet bar have come back from
>   decades past to play a pivotal role in entertaining at home. [...]
>
> (source: '[Raising the bar: If you want the right holiday…](https://www.ocregister.com/2014/12/11/raising-the-bar-if-you-want-the-right-holiday-cocktails-you-need-these-tools/)' by Lisa
>   Liddane for Orange County Register)
>
> (2) Now you're ready for design development, when the architect prepares
>   more detailed drawings showing floor plans with all the rooms in the
>   correct size and shape. **It's the time to picture yourself in these
>   rooms and decide** if you think the traffic flow is good, if the space
>   looks like it will serve the purpose it's built for, if you like the
>   wall and floor finishes and if the doors and windows are of
>   satisfactory size and in the right places.
>
> (source: Chicago Sun-Times. It seems the on-line page is removed already)

Comment: The phrase is "do something" when it's a placeholder for another action. In my experience the word "something" (or "it", "that", "what", etc.) is not optional.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the omission of article the is just for the economy of language, which means if fewer words can convey the whole meaning of a sentence, then there is no reason adding more words.

However, in your examples with "the", though I do not know the specific context that these sentences were used, I could refer that "the time" had been mentioned somewhere before.

Comment: Goodie Good, thanks for your comment. The referent of 'the time' is nowhere to be found in the linguistic context in any of the texts cited. 'Raising the bar' can be reached through the link provided. As a matter of fact, I was told 'It's "the" time to do' is unthinkable by many elsewhere, but I found numerous examples where 'the time' I think is evoked by something except by the text, and awaited or expected; thus, I think 'the' is used.

Answer (score 0):

"It's time to go." You're right that this is the normal expression, and "the time" would feel unnatural. In that sentence, the reference is to a point in time: "We should go now."

Personally, when I first read your two other examples I felt uncomfortable with "the time." But on further reading, there may be a subtle difference. It's possible that "time" in those cases doesn't mean "now", but has a more general meaning. For example:

1. With the holiday season in gear, it's the time to press the cocktail bar into service.
2. The holiday season is the time when we should press the cocktail bar into service.
3. We should press the cocktail bar into service now.

Sentences #2 and #3 are not the same. If the writer's intention was to say #2, then "the time" is a reasonable choice. It's like "Summer is the time to clean the barbeque and get out the surf boards!" "The time" refers to the whole season.

Similarly with the second example. Without full context a bit of guesswork is involved. But it looks like step by step advice on buying or building a holiday home. If so, "the time" refers to one of the stages in that process. In this case, it's design development. So the writer is not saying, It's time to picture yourself now..." She's saying, "When you get to the stage of design development, that's the time when you need to picture yourself in the home and see if it works for you."